# VS 2012 RC 0 With .NET 4.5 - Can't Locate Namespace

Tags: namespaces, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2012

This is likely an easy question for you folks... I added a new project to my solution and I'm trying to add the reference of System.Web.Security namespace but I can't find it? I go to add a reference and looked in Framework and Extensions list and it simply isn't there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well that was stupid. System was reference which is what allowed me to access System.Web but I had to add System.Web to get System.Web.Security. Sometimes I wonder....